# Instance variables are missing from class but present in constructor

Tags: java

There is a class in log4j mentioned below

```
public final class NOPLogger
  extends Logger
{
  public NOPLogger(NOPLoggerRepository repo, String name)
  {
    super(name);
    this.repository = repo;
    this.level = Level.OFF;
    this.parent = this;
  }
```

As you can see four parameters are there in NOPLogger's constructor.

First parameter super(name) I can understand derived from Logger (Parent class), but what about other three instance variables. As per my knowledge they should be declared at class level, but not present as you can see. When I trace those variables, I found them in below class

```
public class Category
  implements AppenderAttachable
{
  protected String name;
  protected volatile Level level;
  protected volatile Category parent;
  private static final String FQCN = Category.class.getName();
  protected ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
  protected LoggerRepository repository;
  AppenderAttachableImpl aai;
  protected boolean additive = true;
```

May I Know please how these three variable taken into consideration in constructor(NOPLogger) without even declaring them at class level first (NOPLogger) ?

I'm just curious to know, and just explained what I've already know (Am I wrong ?) and would like to know where am lagging to understand this concept ?

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Because these three variables are **protected**, so you can modify it in your class

Comment: @0ddlyoko, Okay, but Dont you think so there should be some linkage in between them(NOPLogger<->Category) If am taking them from another class(Category) ?  Or I can just take any where from other class where variables are available publicly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOPLogger` is child of `Logger` that is itself child of `Category`.

> NOPLogger -> Logger -> Category.

And `protected` fields are inherited by  direct subclasses but also by subclasses of them as the [JLS states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)s :

> **6.6.2.1. Access to a protected Member**
>
> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is
>   permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.

`NOPLogger` being a (indirect) subclass of `Category`, it is so expected that a `NOPLogger` instance can access to `protected` instance fields defined in `Category`.

Comment: But how would you know that Logger is a child of Category ? Doesn't seems to be mentioned any linkage in b/w them  ..!

Comment: Open the Logger source code and you will see it. For example : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/Logger.java#Logger

Comment: thanks man for the link , I got it now...In my code it was missing that extends part..!

Comment: You are welcome :) The `Logger` class is common enough in libraries. You probably didn't open the correct one.  I though that your question was about protected on multiple levels. Mybad.

Comment: but cant we use super here ? Or super just go to only one level down ...? Make sense ?

Comment: You can use `super` as prefix but it is not required as the field is inherited.  It would be useful (while not recommended) if the fields was defined twice (super class and current class) to refer one or the other. `super` makes reference to the super class indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The linkage you are after is inheritance hierarchy that `NOPLogger` is declared with. `Category` class has given those three fields protected access, hence there are accessible from subclasses in the inheritance hierarchy. `Catetory -> Logger -> NOPLogger`

```
  protected String   name; 
  volatile protected Level level;
  volatile protected Category parent;
```